# Invalid URI when Connecting Visual Studo to Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, connection, uri

When connecting to Source Control (Azure Devops) for a pull requesgt in Visual Studio (16.4.3), several of us are receiving the error "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGHfm.png)

This started after our company switched us from one domain to another domain. For example:

from \Company1\myuser
to \COMP2\myuser

To date, we've tried restoring the Windows 10 computers (which uninstalled most software) and deleting our own profiles.

We are using the GIT integration.

I'm including the stack trace.

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.PullRequestCreation.PullRequestCreatePageViewModel.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.InitializeViewModel(PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.GitTeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.PullRequestReview.ReviewDescriptionSectionViewModel.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.InitializeViewModel(SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Initialize(Object context)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.PullRequestCreation.PullRequestCommitsSectionViewModel.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.InitializeViewModel(SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Initialize(Object context)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.PullRequestShared.PullRequestChangesSectionViewModel.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.InitializeViewModel(SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerSectionBase.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.PullRequestShared.PullRequestChangesSection.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Initialize(Object context)
```

Comment: Did this behavior/error only occur with pull request in team explorer of Visual Studio? Are you able to use other feature such as work item, or connect git repo in code? Are you able to use pull request feature in web portal without any problems?

Comment: Yes to all of these. It is only pull requests we are having problems with. We can connect with Sourcetree and create branches, do pull requests and view everything else. However, we can't do pull requests within Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi mcross, thanks for your kindly response. According to your description `several of us are receiving the error "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.` If this issue not related to every user in your team. Some works, some not, this should more like a client side issue not server side issue. Have you tried [clear TFS cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-same-location?view=azure-devops#step-6-clear-the-data-cache-on-application-tier-servers) and re-install Visual Studio, which may do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for that information. We are looking into clearing the cache. However, most of the documentation is for in-house server hosting. But, we are in the cloud. I will keep you posted as to what happens as we try to clear the cache.

Comment: UPDATE: Our Azure DevOps is the cloud/web version. We have tried, but we are unable to clear ethe cache, nor can we find documentation to do so. Does anyone have any documentation to help with this?

Comment: Hi mcross, thanks for your update. It's not able to clear server cache if you are using cloud Azure DevOps Service which url should be `https://dev.azure.com/xxx` or `https://xxx.visualstudiaoonline.com`. However, since you have mentioned there is domain changed for your user account. You could give a try with clear local credentials in Visual Studio. Make sure you are using the latest account to connect Visual Studio to Azure DevOps Service. Details please see my below reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to clear server cache if you are using cloud Azure DevOps Service which url should be `https://dev.azure.com/xxx` or `https://xxx.visualstudiaoonline.com`.

However, since you have mentioned there is domain changed for your user account. You could give a try with **clear local credentials in Visual Studio**. Make sure you are using the latest account to connect Visual Studio to Azure DevOps Service.

Some steps may help to clear stored Azure DevOps credentials in Visual Studio 2019:

- Remove the Azure DevOps related credentials from **Credential Manager**
- In Credential Manager add the new updated **Generic Credentials** for the Azure DevOps account.
  Generally, this would overwrite the cached credentials.
- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete
  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`
- Clear all the browser caches especially for the stored password
- Restart Visual Studio  > Team Explorer > Manage Connections to check
  if the `Enter credential dialog` popup. Just try this several times.
  Based on my test the dialog will popup the first time, but if you cancel
  it, then you have to restart VS to popup it again.
- Run Visual Studio as another user:

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

  `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`

  Enter the user possword, then `Team Explorer` > `Manage Connections`